# How can I pass the post's id through the client during testing in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing

```
def test_sharing_post_through_email(self):
        form = {'name': 'Martin', 'email': 'exampel.example@gmail.com', 'to': 'Martinals@gmail.com'}
        
        response = self.client.post('/<int:id>/share/', data={'post': self.post, 'form': form})
        response.user = self.user

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIsInstance(response.context, dict)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['sent'], True)
```

**how can I pass the ID to the url there?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reverse` from `django.urls`. Lets supose your url is defined in `urls.py` as:

```
path('/<int:id>/share/', views.share_view, name="share_view")
```

You could pass the *id* with reverse as:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def test_sharing(self):
    url = reverse("share_view", kwargs={"id": 1234})
    response = self.client.post(url, data={"post": "1"})
```

You'll have to use the app name in the reverse calling. If your targeted view is in the app "home":

```
url = reverse("home:share_view", kwargs={"id": 1234})
```

Comment: Oh! I had tried this before but I had a syntax error! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I know I can use RequestFactory but I want to have access to the context of the view

Comment: So you ask a question, and then change it in the comments... Quite difficult to help you.

Comment: Also, RequestFactory won't change nothing. You still need to resolve the url, with the id param, when calling the `get` method of RequestFactory.